# Determining number of vertices in R

Tags: r, google-earth-engine

How can I determine the number of vertices in an object in R? (Similar question here: [Extract number of vertices in each polygon in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/58147), has not worked for me)

I am trying to upload the National Burned Area Composite 2019 from Canada to Google Earth Engine, link here: https://cwfis.cfs.nrcan.gc.ca/datamart/metadata/nbac

However, many of the features have too many vertices to upload:

[image]

In R, I can use st_simplify from the 'sf' package on individual features from the shapefile. However, I only know which features to apply this to after failing to upload the shapefile to GEE. This takes painfully long as GEE only tells me one of the features with too many vertices on each attempt to upload.

I'd love a way to tell in R which features have more than 1,000,000 vertices. Here is the head() for my sf object.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is for an sp, not sf, object and is dated information. The coordinates of an sf polygon or line object represent the vertices as opposed to the centroids in an sp class object. So, `st_coordinates` returns a matrix where the number of rows represent number of vertices. This can be aggregated out by the unique id column in the returned in the matrix.

An iteration approach could be done using lapply. In your case I would first explode the geometry so that the polygons are single part.

```
x <- st_cast(x, "POLYGON")
unlist(lapply(1:nrow(x), \(i) nrow(st_coordinates(x[i,])) )
```

This will return a vector of number of vertices per feature, ordered the same as the input features. If you are going to simplify the geometry, based on number of vertices, you really want to operate on a per-polygon basis.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still running into challenges as my code is not returning all the features with over 1,000,000 vertices.



`matrix_coordinates = sf::st_coordinates(sf_fires)
df_coordinates = as.data.frame(matrix_coordinates)

vertices_per_fire <- df_coordinates %>%
  group_by(L3) %>%
  summarise(NumVertices = n())

vert_over_max <- vertices_per_fire %>%
  filter(NumVertices > 1000000)`

Results: print(vert_over_max)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     L3 NumVertices
  <dbl>       <int>
1    33     1145063
2    36     1190027
3   179     1069664

However, I know feature 29 has too many

Comment: No idea on why results would be truncated at a certain number. Perhaps try iterating. See my addition to the answer using `lapply`. I will note that things may get weird with MULTIPOLYGON geometry.